# How can I get run adb logcat

Tags: android

I installed android sdk on windows. How can I run the adb logcat with a GUI? I can only get the command version to run.

Answer (score 6):

Either run the `ddms` tool from your `ANDROID-SDK\tools` folder, or add the logcat view to eclipse via `Window -> Show View -> Other -> Logcat`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much of a GUI to logcat.  If you don't want to run it from the command line, you can also run it in eclipse.  But even in eclipse, it's pretty similar to running from the command line but you get some colors and filters.

You can also make logcat a little easier on the eyes with a script like this one: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

You could run DDMS which has a logcat GUI (with color and filtering).

I'm not sure how to start DDMS from Windows.